# Populating ListView with ORMLite

Tags: android, listview, ormlite

I need to populate ListView with List of objects returned from my Dao object.
The items get returned after 3 seconds, obviously to much time for the user to wait...
I'm using BaseAdapter as the ListView adapter.

2 questions:

1. How can get rid of the 3 seconds waiting time? Should I just retrieve the entire list of objects in a seperate worker Thread and display dialog in the meanwhile? Is there any mechanism that allows me to get the first, let's say... 20 records, display them and fetch the rest of the records while the user scrolls down the list?
2. If I would use cursors, rather than ORMLite, the list would then query the DB as the user scrolls down the list, releasing the objects of the hidden cells and the cells themselves, and not keeping all the objects of the cursor in the memory. How can I achieve this behavior with ORMLite?

I hope I was clear enough, despite the bad English ;)

Thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You might want to load the data in an `AsyncTask`, and display a `ProgressDialog` while it loads. Lot of Android apps do this.

Cannot OrmLite return a DataProvider instead of the while list? (I too wanted to look into ORM on Android but the management decided against it "Its slow", but I still badly want it)

Comment: I'm familiar with `AsyncTask` and dialogs, but I really want to use ORM of some sort, and ORMLite seems to be the right (and free) choice for the moment... Maybe I should also to use `Cursor`'s and that's it...